# How to compile java 1.3 code with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I need to compile a rather old project which uses java language level 1.3. Language level 1.3 must be used, since all classes use the default package and importing classes from the default package isn't allowed on higher language levels.

I was able to compile the project by changing the language level to 1.3 in my Eclipse configuration, but have trouble using gradle. I added `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` to my build.gradle file:

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.3
    targetCompatibility = 1.3
}
```

which produces the following warnings:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.3
warning: [options] source value 1.3 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.3 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
```

but compiling fails pointing me to the import statements:

```
...\src\Foo.java:
10: error: '.' expected
import Bar;
```

My question is: How to compile Java 1.3 code using gradle without changing the code?

**gradle -v:**

```
Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Comment: Does your code compile without setting the targetCompatibility (i.e. using 1.6/1.7/whatever)?

Comment: Have you made sure that your code is actually compatible with java 1.3?

Comment: And is there any reason you don't want to fix the code by putting it in a named package? That's likely to be much more productive in the long term.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki I tried changing targetCompatibility but I get the same error, which seems plausible to me.

Comment: @Jorge_B yes, I can compile the project using Eclipse (when using language level 1.3).

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I plan to introduce packages later on, but want to run and test the unchanged source first. If the answer is, gradle can't do it, I might skip this step.

Answer (score 0):

The error message was misleading. The sourceCompatibility was indeed configured right, Bar just wasn't found, because of a missing dependency. My bad.

Comment: What missing dependency?

Comment: Just an arbitrary library I've used in my project